# How to write couple of lines into a file in C?

Tags: c

I'm having a variable called `username` and another one called `password`...

I need to register users into a system, and write it on a file..
My problem is, that the 2nd time or more, it writes the details on the same line..

For example :

in the first time I write for the file, it become something like this :

`Amit 123456`

but on the second time I'm registering a user, it doesnt go to the next line and keep writing from that spot:

`Amit 123456Yosi 125818`
where I need the file to be like this :

```
Amit 123456
Yosi 125818
```

I mean, I need to make the 2nd or more `fprintf` to the file go to the next line, and not to start from the specific place...

I've wrote this in the code :

```
fprintf(file, "%s %s\n", username, password);
```

though, the `'\n'`doesnt seems to make the next `fprintf` go to the next line...

In summery - I need to print to the file every time, on a new line..

on the first print to the file, it'll write on line 1
then on the second print to the file, it'll write on line 2, and not from the continue of line1...

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try \r\n? Different platform have different end-of-line encodings.

Comment: Are you on Windows? You may need \n\r

Comment: @AmitM9S6 Are you perhaps opening the file every time you write to it ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows OS, jacknad -  no, this is not homework...
@nos yes,I do open it every time to write on it...

Comment: You need to open file in append mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same thought as the commenters: You may need a `\r` in there too, depending on your development environment. It could even be that the file viewer you are using is the issue (eg: Notepad.exe on Windows often has trouble with simple line endings)

Comment: *Whew*. Ok. I can sleep now. You really shouldn't scare us like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on Windows, you need /r/n

Note that it is very, very bad practice to save passwords, please google how to work with passwords.

Comment: It isnt a normal save, it has encryption, and on a binary file..
Also, it's a practice I've built for my self.. on a real program, I wouldent just put a password like that on a file :)